# Date range selector for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, date

Is there a control which allow select date range for WPF. It should look like this picture.
[image]

Or what should I do to make that control?

Comment: there's no range selector build in as far as i know, but you can use 3rd party selectors like [this one](https://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2007/09/10/rangeslider-support-control-templates/)

Comment: @styx, I try to found 3rd party libs, but I find nothing. I saw link which you write, but I see "Oops! That page can’t be found." when I try to download example.

Comment: you can view the source code [here](https://github.com/jogibear9988/avaloncontrolslib/blob/master/AvalonControlsLibrary/Controls/RangeSlider.cs)

Comment: Maybe I will use something from this lib, but it can not work with date.

Comment: I have created a DateRangeSelector as a UserControl for my own project. It is relatively easy if you do not need to overcomplicate it with special requirements. Mine is practically two DatePickers in a panel, with some codebehind to make sure the first selected date is the earlier one.

Comment: @mami, I thought about it, but I need to realize more complicated behavior than DatePicker allow. It should look like date selector on booking.com. I think I make own control (with blackjack and etc. =)) to reach my goal.

Comment: You can also take a look at the the Calendar control: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.calendar

Comment: @mami, I thought about it, but I decided that existed controls don't fit for me. I work on own control which similar to CalendarItem.